How to implement conditional XAML compilation using MSBuild and XSLT?
Following this question, I want to conditionally include/exclude XAML elements at build time based on preprocessor directives, similar to how #if/#else works in C#. I've tried using XSLT to transform the XAML, but it's not working as expected.
What I'm Trying to Achieve
I define preprocessor constants in my .csproj:
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;fix_issue_001</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

Then in XAML, I want to conditionally include elements based on these constants:
<Window x:Class="XamlPreprocessDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- fix_issue_001:true -->
        <Button Content="Original version" Click="Button_Click" />
        <!-- end fix_issue_001:true -->
        <!-- fix_issue_001:false -->
        <Button Content="New version" Background="LightGreen" Click="Button_Click" />
        <!-- end fix_issue_001:false -->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

My Attempted Solution
Here's my XSLT (Transform.xslt):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:param name="DefineConstants" select="''"/>
    
    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Skip end markers -->
    <xsl:template match="comment()[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'end fix_')]"/>

    <!-- Handle conditional comments -->
    <xsl:template match="comment()[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'fix_')]">
        <xsl:variable name="content" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="endMarker" select="concat('end ', substring-before($content, ':'))"/>
        
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- True condition -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($content, ':true')">
                <xsl:variable name="constant" select="substring-before($content, ':true')"/>
                <xsl:if test="contains($DefineConstants, $constant)">
                    <xsl:variable name="endComment" select="following-sibling::comment()
                        [normalize-space(.) = concat('end ', $constant, ':true')][1]"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                        [generate-id(preceding-sibling::comment()
                            [contains(., concat($constant, ':true'))][1]) = generate-id(current())
                        and following-sibling::comment()
                            [normalize-space(.) = concat('end ', $constant, ':true')][1]
                            and generate-id(.) != generate-id($endComment)]"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- False condition -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($content, ':false')">
                <xsl:variable name="constant" select="substring-before($content, ':false')"/>
                <xsl:if test="not(contains($DefineConstants, $constant))">
                    <xsl:variable name="endComment" select="following-sibling::comment()
                        [normalize-space(.) = concat('end ', $constant, ':false')][1]"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                        [generate-id(preceding-sibling::comment()
                            [contains(., concat($constant, ':false'))][1]) = generate-id(current())
                        and following-sibling::comment()
                            [normalize-space(.) = concat('end ', $constant, ':false')][1]
                            and generate-id(.) != generate-id($endComment)]"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

And here's my MSBuild integration (XamlPreprocess.targets):
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="XamlPreprocessTask"
             TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputFile ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <OutputFile ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <DefineConstants ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <TransformFile ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.Xml"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.Xml.Xsl"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          try {
              var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
              transform.Load(TransformFile);
              
              var args = new XsltArgumentList();
              args.AddParam("DefineConstants", "", DefineConstants);
              
              var outputDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(OutputFile);
              if (!Directory.Exists(outputDir))
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);
              
              using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(OutputFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
                  writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                  transform.Transform(InputFile, args, writer);
              }
              
              return true;
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
              Log.LogError($"XAML preprocessing failed: {ex.Message}");
              return false;
          }
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <XamlPreprocessDir>$(IntermediateOutputPath)PreprocessedXaml\</XamlPreprocessDir>
    <XamlTransformFile>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Transform.xslt</XamlTransformFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PreprocessXaml" BeforeTargets="MarkupCompilePass1;XamlMarkupCompilePass1">
    <ItemGroup>
      <XamlFiles Include="**\*.xaml" 
                Exclude="$(XamlPreprocessDir)**\*.xaml;**\.vshistory\**\*.xaml;App.xaml;bin\**\*.xaml;obj\**\*.xaml" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <MakeDir Directories="$(XamlPreprocessDir)" />

    <XamlPreprocessTask
      InputFile="%(XamlFiles.FullPath)"
      OutputFile="$(XamlPreprocessDir)%(XamlFiles.RecursiveDir)%(XamlFiles.Filename)%(XamlFiles.Extension)"
      DefineConstants="$(DefineConstants)"
      TransformFile="$(XamlTransformFile)">
    </XamlPreprocessTask>

    <!-- Copy the preprocessed files to a temporary backup -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(XamlFiles)" 
          DestinationFiles="@(XamlFiles->'$(XamlPreprocessDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename).original%(Extension)')" />

    <!-- Copy the preprocessed files over the originals -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(XamlFiles->'$(XamlPreprocessDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
          DestinationFiles="@(XamlFiles)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="RestoreXaml" AfterTargets="MarkupCompilePass1;XamlMarkupCompilePass1">
    <!-- Restore the original files -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(XamlFiles->'$(XamlPreprocessDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename).original%(Extension)')"
          DestinationFiles="@(XamlFiles)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanPreprocessedXaml" BeforeTargets="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(XamlPreprocessDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>

The Problem
The XSLT transformation seems to have no effect - both buttons are showing up in the final application, regardless of whether fix_issue_001 is defined or not. I expect to see only the "Original version" button when fix_issue_001 is defined, and only the "New version" button when it's not.

Requirements

Must work with Visual Studio 2019
Should preserve XAML designer functionality
Should not modify source files permanently
Ideally integrated with MSBuild process

Question

Why isn't my XSLT transformation working?
Is there a better approach to achieve conditional XAML compilation?

P.S. I believe I have managed to solve this problem. You may find the source code here and the NuGet package here.

Possibly related: Does XAML have a conditional compiler directive for debug mode

@JonasH yeah the question is indeed relevant. lots and lots of people have asked similar questions. But none of them seem as elegant as XSLT, if it works. For example the answers on that page do not seem to use the DefineConstants and they require altering the old code as far as I understand.

Since one can do this all with "code behind" (building UserControls on the fly), this is only a problem when one insists on using "ALL" XAML for the "target points" in the first place. The "optional" parts can be abstracted to user controls to start with; or after the fact; which is the same as trying to figure out how to make it "conditional". In other cases, one simply "prunes" the tree after it's loaded (deleting visual children is trivial if they're stand-alone to start with)

In XSLT 3, you could use code like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="collect-to-delete" as="xs:boolean" initial-value="false()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="comment()[matches(., '^\s*fix_issue_[0-9]*:false\s*$')]" select="true()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="comment()[matches(., '^\s*end fix_issue_[0-9]*:false\s*$')]" select="false()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="delete" as="element()*" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*[accumulator-before('collect-to-delete')]" select="$value, ."/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="collect-to-delete delete"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="comment()[matches(., '^\s*fix_issue_[0-9]*:(true|false)\s*$')]"/>

    <xsl:template match="comment()[matches(., '^\s*end fix_issue_[0-9]*:(true|false)\s*$')]"/>
      
    <xsl:template match="*[accumulator-before('delete') intersect .]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

to transform
<Window x:Class="XamlPreprocessDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- fix_issue_001:true -->
        <Button Content="Original version" Click="Button_Click" />
        <!-- end fix_issue_001:true -->
        <!-- fix_issue_001:false -->
        <Button Content="New version" Background="LightGreen" Click="Button_Click" />
        <!-- end fix_issue_001:false -->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

into
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="XamlPreprocessDemo.MainWindow" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        
        <Button Content="Original version" Click="Button_Click"/>
        
        
        
        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

That could be run with .NET framework/C# and Saxon HE 10, for instance. And it should be easier to adapt and debug than XSLT 1.0.

I believe I have managed to solve this problem. You may find the source code here and the NuGet package here.

@FoadS.Farimani, so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79258069/xslt-preprocessor-for-conditional-xaml-not-working-despite-correct-parameter-val is resolved as well? What was missing?

I think the an answer I have here is more elegant and less destructive than the approach I had over there. So that post is no longer a priority for me,.
