XSLT preprocessor for conditional XAML not working despite correct parameter value
Following this question, I'm trying to implement conditional XAML compilation using XSLT preprocessing in a WPF application. While the XSLT transformation appears to run successfully and outputs the expected XAML, the GUI doesn't show the expected content.
The Setup
I have a custom MSBuild task that processes XAML files using XSLT to handle conditional compilation based on defined constants. Here's a minimal example that reproduces the issue:
you may replicate the issue by cloning and checking out this commit.

First, create a new WPF application and add these files:

CustomTasks/Class1.cs - Custom MSBuild task for XSLT transformation:
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace CustomTasks
{
    public class XsltTransformTask : Task
    {
        [Required]
        public ITaskItem[] InputFiles { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ITaskItem[] OutputFiles { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string XsltFile { get; set; }

        public string Parameters { get; set; }

        private void LogDebugInfo(string message)
        {
            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, $"[DEBUG] {message}");
        }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            try
            {
                LogDebugInfo($"Starting XSLT transformation");
                LogDebugInfo($"XSLT file: {XsltFile}");
                LogDebugInfo($"Raw parameters: {Parameters}");

                var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                {
                    DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
                    IgnoreWhitespace = false
                };

                var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(XsltFile, settings))
                {
                    xslt.Load(reader);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < InputFiles.Length; i++)
                {
                    var inputFile = InputFiles[i].ItemSpec;
                    var outputFile = OutputFiles[i].ItemSpec;
                    LogDebugInfo($"Processing {inputFile} -> {outputFile}");

                    var xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters))
                    {
                        foreach (var param in Parameters.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        {
                            var kvp = param.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2);
                            if (kvp.Length == 2)
                            {
                                string paramName = kvp[0].Trim();
                                string paramValue = kvp[1].Trim();
                                LogDebugInfo($"Parameter: {paramName} = {paramValue}");
                                xsltArgs.AddParam(paramName, "", paramValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var outputDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFile);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputDir) && !System.IO.Directory.Exists(outputDir))
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);
                    }

                    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputFile, settings))
                    {
                        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
                        {
                            Indent = true,
                            IndentChars = "    ",
                            NewLineChars = "\n",
                            NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
                        };

                        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFile, writerSettings))
                        {
                            xslt.Transform(reader, xsltArgs, writer);
                        }
                    }

                    LogDebugInfo($"Transformation completed for {inputFile}");
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(outputFile))
                    {
                        string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(outputFile);
                        LogDebugInfo($"Transformed content:\n{content}");
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.LogErrorFromException(ex, true);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

PreprocessXaml.xslt - XSLT file for preprocessing:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:pp="http://schemas.example.com/preprocessor"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="pp">

    <!-- Parameter -->
    <xsl:param name="fix_issue_001" select="'False'" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template to process pp:If elements -->
    <xsl:template match="pp:If">
        <xsl:variable name="condition" select="@Condition" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with($condition, '!')">
                <xsl:if test="$fix_issue_001 = 'false' or $fix_issue_001 = 'False'">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="$fix_issue_001 = 'true' or $fix_issue_001 = 'True'">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

MainWindow.xaml - Main window with conditional XAML:
<Window x:Class="ConditionalXamlApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:pp="http://schemas.example.com/preprocessor"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="pp"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="200"
        Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <pp:If Condition="fix_issue_001">
            <TextBlock Text="Original version"
                       Margin="10" />
        </pp:If>
        <pp:If Condition="!fix_issue_001">
            <TextBlock Text="New version"
                       Margin="10"
                       Background="LightGreen" />
        </pp:If>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

ConditionalXamlApp.csproj - Project file with MSBuild customizations:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- Standard WPF project properties omitted for brevity -->
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;fix_issue_001</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <XsltStylesheet>PreprocessXaml.xslt</XsltStylesheet>
        <TempXamlDir>$(IntermediateOutputPath)PreprocessedXaml\</TempXamlDir>
        <IsFixIssue001Defined>false</IsFixIssue001Defined>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <IsFixIssue001Defined Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('$(DefineConstants)').Contains('fix_issue_001'))">true</IsFixIssue001Defined>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="PreprocessXaml" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
        <ItemGroup>
            <XamlFiles Include="**\*.xaml" Exclude="$(TempXamlDir)**\*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(TempXamlDir)" />
        <Message Text="IsFixIssue001Defined = $(IsFixIssue001Defined)" Importance="high" />
        <XsltTransformTask 
            InputFiles="@(XamlFiles)" 
            OutputFiles="@(XamlFiles->'$(TempXamlDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
            XsltFile="$(XsltStylesheet)" 
            Parameters="fix_issue_001=$(IsFixIssue001Defined)" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <Page Remove="@(XamlFiles)" />
            <Page Include="$(TempXamlDir)**\*.xaml" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\CustomTasks\CustomTasks.csproj">
            <Project>{e144387a-4d72-4c6f-bf17-8e2bc1c9d9e9}</Project>
            <Name>CustomTasks</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <UsingTask TaskName="CustomTasks.XsltTransformTask" AssemblyFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)TempTasks\CustomTasks.dll" />

</Project>

build.bat - Build script:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Initialize flags
set CLEAN=0
set RUN=0

REM Process command-line arguments
:process_args
if "%~1"=="" goto after_args
if /I "%~1"=="clean" set CLEAN=1
if /I "%~1"=="run" set RUN=1
shift
goto process_args

:after_args

REM If CLEAN is specified, perform cleaning
if %CLEAN%==1 (
    echo Cleaning bin and obj and PreprocessedXaml directories...
    for /d /r %%d in (bin,obj,PreprocessedXaml) do (
        if exist "%%d" (
            echo Deleting directory: "%%d"
            rd /s /q "%%d"
        )
    )
)

REM Build the solution using MSBuild
echo Building solution using MSBuild...
msbuild "ConditionalXamlApp.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /verbosity:minimal /nologo /fileLogger

REM Check if build succeeded
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Build failed.
    exit /b 1
) else (
    echo Build succeeded.
)

REM If RUN is specified, run the application
if %RUN%==1 (
    echo Running application...
    start "" "ConditionalXamlApp\bin\Debug\ConditionalXamlApp.exe"
)

endlocal

The Issue
When I run build clean run, the build succeeds and the XSLT transformation appears to work correctly:
Cleaning bin and obj and PreprocessedXaml directories...
Deleting directory: "C:\dev\Csharp\20241205\ConditionalXamlApp\ConditionalXamlApp\bin"
Deleting directory: "C:\dev\Csharp\20241205\ConditionalXamlApp\ConditionalXamlApp\obj"
Deleting directory: "C:\dev\Csharp\20241205\ConditionalXamlApp\ConditionalXamlApp\PreprocessedXaml"
Deleting directory: "C:\dev\Csharp\20241205\ConditionalXamlApp\CustomTasks\bin"
Deleting directory: "C:\dev\Csharp\20241205\ConditionalXamlApp\CustomTasks\obj"
Building solution using MSBuild...
  CustomTasks -> C:\dev\Csharp\20241205\ConditionalXamlApp\CustomTasks\bin\Debug\CustomTasks.dll
  [DEBUG] Starting XSLT transformation
  [DEBUG] XSLT file: PreprocessXaml.xslt
  [DEBUG] Raw parameters: fix_issue_001=True
  [DEBUG] Processing MainWindow.xaml -> PreprocessedXaml\MainWindow.xaml
  [DEBUG] Parameter: fix_issue_001 = True
  [DEBUG] Transformation completed for MainWindow.xaml
  [DEBUG] Transformed content:
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Window x:Class="ConditionalXamlApp.MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="pp" Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:pp="http://schemas.example.com/preprocessor" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="Original version" Margin="10" />
      </StackPanel>
  </Window>
  ConditionalXamlApp -> C:\dev\Csharp\20241205\ConditionalXamlApp\ConditionalXamlApp\bin\Debug\ConditionalXamlApp.exe
Build succeeded.
Running application...

However, when the application runs, no TextBlock is shown in the GUI window

, even though:

The fix_issue_001 constant is defined in the Debug configuration
The XSLT transformation logs show the parameter is being passed as True
The transformed XAML output shows the correct TextBlock being included

What am I missing here? Why isn't the TextBlock showing up in the GUI despite being present in the transformed XAML?
What I've Tried

Verified the constant is defined in the Debug configuration
Added debug logging to both MSBuild and the XSLT transformation
Made the XSLT boolean checks case-insensitive
Verified the transformed XAML contains the expected content

Any help would be appreciated!
P.S. I believe I have managed to solve this problem. You may find the source code here and the NuGet package here.

It doesn't look like an XSLT problem to me if the XSLT produces the wanted XML/XAML.

Just as a quick test to simplify, if you move the TextBlock outside of the pp:If does it render?

@MadsHansen yes it does.

@MadsHansen yeah the XSLT seems to be working perfectly fine. I is really baffling!

So, maybe simplify the question and just ask about the pp:If - seems like the XSLT is irrelevant.

@MadsHansen I tried asking a simplified and concise question here but it was downvoted and blocked. So here I am aiming for reproducibility. I tried explaining what I want and what I have so far and where I am stuk.

@MadsHansen another strange thing I have noticed since positing is that all pp:If blocks are omitted regardless. This is really strange and I have no clue why is this the case! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
